# Using a BOOL method to filter uitableviewcells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I am trying to use this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602) to change my `UITableViewCell` depending on if the user has posted a picture or not.I am also using [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) for my data not an rss feed. For the most part I have everything working except for the `BOOL` method to see if a picture exisit with that post. This is what i could think of so far

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{

        if ([self hasImageAtIndexPath:indexPath]) {
              return [self pictureCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      } else {
            return [self pictureCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     }
}


- (BOOL)hasImageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

      PFObject *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
      PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"post"];
     [query whereKey:@"HasPicture" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

     return true;
 }
```

I have been trying to figure this out for quite sometime and any help  would be greatly appreciated, I can put up more code if need be or answer anything that is unclear.

Comment: Two problems with what you are doing: if `hasImageAtIndexPath:` is synchronous it might cause delays of table update, if it does any networking this issue becomes critical; if `hasImageAtIndexPath:` is asynchronous it's going to always return YES and is quite useless for what you are trying to achieve. Check any tutorial of async images loading into a `UITableView`, it will have a similar problem and a solution that you could try to apply to your project.

Comment: Ive looked at what you have suggested and its not what I'm looking for. I just need to return a different cell based upon if they have posted a picture or not.

Comment: Your description of what you are doing is too board, an approach to do it completely depends on what kind of information you have and the ways you can access it.

Comment: Well my information comes from Parse.com, would it help if i added all the code for this view?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should look at their API implementation instead of you ? Because I don't think I want to do that, on the other hand if you do that it might explain everything or provide much needed background.